# How to generate right click event when left click event generated?

Tags: cocoa

I want to generate right click event on same object,on which left click event generated.

Object on which I need to generate is a 'context menu'. And as we know context menu opens only at its right click.
So I want to open context menu on its left click by simply generating right click event on left click.

Anyone can help me for same?

Comment: I wil..now will you please answer my question.I really mesh with this.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by assigning a menu to my button in interface builder and then subclass NSButton so that the menu is displayed on mouse down (left click).

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [self setState:NSOnState];
    [self highlight:YES];

    if ([self menu])
    {
      [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:[self menu] withEvent:theEvent forView:self];
    }

    [self setState:NSOffState];
    [self highlight:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 / iOS 10 version for Scott's answer:

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)
{
    super.mouseDown(with: event)

    if let menu = self.menu
    {
        let locationInView = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        menu.popUp(positioning: nil, at: locationInView, in: self)
    }
}
```